# Yii2: how to specify multiples database schemas?

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2, database-schema, yii2-advanced-app

I am using PostgreSQL and the default database schema in my Yii2 application.

I created a new schema called **laboratory** and I need to define it in the common/config/main-local.php file.

This is my current **main-local.php** file:

```
<?php
return [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=travel',
            'username' => 'aaaa',
            'password' => 'bbbb',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
    ],
];
```

How can I add the laboratory schema in this file? I need both schemas.

Is Yii2 supporting multiples schemas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't necessary to change it:

```
<?php
return [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=travel',
            'username' => 'aaaa',
            'password' => 'bbbb',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Then Gii code generator recognizes the laboratory schema (but autocomplete for **Table Name** doesn't work).

Answer (score 2):

You can configure more than one in components

```
      return [
      'components' => [
          'db1' => [
              'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
              'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb1',
              'username' => 'demo1',
              'password' => 'demo1',
          ],
          'db2' => [
              'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
              'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb2',
              'username' => 'demo2',
              'password' => 'demo2',
          ],

      ],
  ];
```

and you can refer to each one using

```
 \Yii::$app->db1;  

 or 

  \Yii::$app->db2;
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-databases.html

for postgresql  you could try

```
      return [
      'components' => [
          'db1' => [
              'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
              'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb1',
              'username' => 'demo1',
              'password' => 'demo1',
              'schemaMap' => [
                'pgsql'=> [
                  'class'=>'yii\db\pgsql\Schema',
                  'defaultSchema' => 'your_schema1' //specify your schema here
                ]
              ],
          ],
          'db2' => [
              'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
              'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb2',
              'username' => 'demo2',
              'password' => 'demo2',
              'schemaMap' => [
                'pgsql'=> [
                  'class'=>'yii\db\pgsql\Schema',
                  'defaultSchema' => 'your_schema2' //specify your schema here
                ]
              ],
          ],

      ],
  ];
```

Comment: Where can I specify my new schema called laboratory?

Comment: In MySQL, physically, a schema is synonymous with a database. so you try using the database related  name ..

Comment: It's a PostgreSQL database. Anyway I tried your MySQL solution but it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't have two database. Maybe your solution works for two databaste. I have one PostgreSQL database with two schemas.