# Yii2 migration flexible Database Engine

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql, yii2, database-migration

I have an application in PHP with framework `Yii2`. I want this application to be running with some database engine like Postgresql, MySql or SQL Server. The problem is how to migrate it. You know, for instance, Postgresql and SQL Server use schemas as subsets of database but not MySQL.

I was developing my application with Postgresql with some schemas like, `history`, `main` and `log`. Now I want to try run my application with MySQL. What must I to do to achieve this?

```
POSTGRESQL
    my_database -> database name
        main -> schema
            tables
        history -> schema
            tables
```

I want my migration can be running whatever you use database engine (postgresql, mssql or mysql), without controller / models / etc.

Comment: If your migration file contains database engine specific things you must either create new migration files or rewrite the migration file to make it engine agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the `yii\db\Migration` and add conditionals depending on the type of database system you are using in every method.

For example, for defaults applying to all methods, I extend `yii\db\Migration` and override `init()`

```
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        switch ($this->db->driverName) {
            case 'mysql':
                $this->tableOptions = 'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE=InnoDB';
                $this->dbType = 'mysql';
                break;
            case 'pgsql':
                // specifics for pgsql
            default:
                throw new \RuntimeException('Your database is not supported!');
        }
    }
```

Then all your migrations should extend this one.

According to this, with the same migration you can do specific operations for specific database systems.

Comment: how about if i have an activerecord model which tableName = 'history.user_login'? in postgresql 'history' is schema. how mysql handle this?

Comment: Don't know specifics on pgsql. The idea of my post is that Yii allows to identify the db type you are using, so you can add specific code for every one. Your original question was about migration. Perhaps you should ask another about Yii2 Active Records and PostgreSQL or check the seconds answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47228767/yii2-how-to-specify-multiples-database-schemas/47263899. You can specify the db connection each Active Record if you override [getDb()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#getDb()-detail)

Comment: okay, thanks for your answer @gabriel-a-lópez-lópez

Comment: its updated now with references, I think there is your solution

Comment: yeah. from your reference, i think my Active Record model need to improve when using mysql. so we need more database connection, because mysql will create new database as schema. For mysql one connection for one schema (database). That's good solution for now. Thanks bro!